# Unknown array notation javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays

I've come across the following code, I'm having trouble getting my head around it.

`selCOption2[i, 'labelname'] = selOption2Arr[i];`

a larger excerpt

```
var selCOption2 = [];
    var stringContent = '';


    jQuery('#txtTypes').attr("value", selOption1);

    for(var i=0; i<selOption2Arr.length; i++) {
      if(selOption2Arr[i] != 'Plain' || selOption2Arr[i] != 'plain') {
        selCOption2[i, 'labelname'] = selOption2Arr[i];
        selCOption2[i, 'keyname'] = keyname+"_"+selOption2Arr[i].toLowerCase()+"_"+selOption3Arr[0].toLowerCase();
        for(var ifm = 0; ifm < proJsonDetails.images.length; ifm++) {   
          if(proJsonDetails.images[ifm].indexOf(selCOption2[i, 'keyname']) > 0) {
            selCOption2[i, 'image'] = proJsonDetails.images[ifm];
          }
        }
      }
    }
```

Comment: `selCOption2[i]['labelname'] = selOption2Arr[i];`

Comment: This is valid syntax, but not a sensible thing to do. The expression "`i, 'labelname'`" is a [comma operator expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comma_Operator), and the effect is no different from `selCOption2['labelname'] = ...` (except for the highly unusual case where there might be a getter function on `i`, which is not the case here).

Comment: …and so what you have is equivalent with `selCOption2['labelname'] = selOption2Arr[i];`.

Answer (score 4):

See a reduced test case:

```
var a = [ 'x', 'y', 'z' ];
var o = {};
var i = 1;
o[i, 'labelname'] = a[i];
console.log(o);
```

which gives:

```
{ labelname: 'y' }
```

The [`,` operator](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-11.14) evaluates as whatever is on the right hand side of it.

There doesn't appear to be any point in having `i,` in that code.